# Disable vibration alert in samsung fame

Tags: vibration, samsung-galaxy-fame

Have moved to Samsung Galaxy Fame from a Samsung Galaxy Mini which died. Via settings>sound have disabled vibrate alert for incoming calls, how do I do the same for incoming texts please?

Answer (score 1):

Vibration on my Samsung, which is a Galaxy S3, is controlled from within the Messaging app itself. Start the app. Settings > Notifications > Vibrate. Uncheck.

Comment: If you are using Hangouts as the SMS app it's the same thing Hangouts > Settings > SMS > Vibrate and uncheck. Android handles notifications on an app by app basis so everthing you want vibrate off on needs to be set individually.